# Unmarshal a specific XML file from zip without extracting

Tags: xml, go, zip

I have a zip file having several xml files in it using [zip](https://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/) and [encoding/xml](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/) packages from Go archive. The thing I want to do is unmarshalling **only** `a.xml` into a type -i.e. without looping over all files inside:

```
test.zip
├ a.xml
├ b.xml
└ ...
```

`a.xml` would have a structure like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <app>
        <code>0001</code>
        <name>Some Test App</name>
    </app>
    <app>
        <code>0002</code>
        <name>Another Test App</name>
    </app>
</root>
```

How to for select and unmarshal the file whose name is provided as a parameter in the commented out lines, for instance:

```
package marshalutils

import (
    "archive/zip"
    "log"
    "fmt"
    "encoding/xml"
)

type ApplicationRoot struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"root"`
    Applications []Application `xml:"app"`
}

type Application struct {
    Code string `xml:"code"`
    Name string `xml:"name"`
}

func UnmarshalApps(zipPath string, fileName string) {
    // Open a zip archive for reading.
    reader, err := zip.OpenReader(zipFilePath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(`ERROR:`, err)
    }

    defer reader.Close()

    /* 
     * U N M A R S H A L   T H E   G I V E N   F I L E ...
     * ... I N T O   T H E   T Y P E S   A B O V E
     */
}
```

Comment: The documentation examples show how to use a [`zip.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/#example_Reader). Just skip the files you don't want.

Comment: So, no way it can be done without looping and checking the name?

Comment: A zip file contains a list of the file names; how would you look for the name in a list without looping over that list? You don't have to extract every file, loop over the names just like in that example in the docs.

Comment: ok, how about the unmarshalling part, I mean the usage of ReadCloser with encoding/xml's Unmarshal method

Comment: You can read it and use `xml.Unmarshal`, or use an `xml.Decoder`. This is no different from unmarshaling any other `io.Reader`. If you're having a problem using the `xml` package, I would make a specific question with an example of where you're having trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is the answer I have found with the return type declaration added to the sample function:

```
func UnmarshalApps(zipPath string, fileName string) ApplicationRoot {
    // Open a zip archive for reading.
    reader, err := zip.OpenReader(zipFilePath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(`ERROR:`, err)
    }

    defer reader.Close()

    /* 
     * START OF ANSWER
     */
    var appRoot ApplicationRoot
    for _, file := range reader.File {
        // check if the file matches the name for application portfolio xml
        if file.Name == fileName {
            rc, err := file.Open()
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(`ERROR:`, err)
            }

            // Prepare buffer
            buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
            buf.ReadFrom(rc)

            // Unmarshal bytes
            xml.Unmarshal(buf.Bytes(), &appRoot)
            rc.Close()
        }
    }   
     /* 
     * END OF ANSWER
     */     
}
```